# Unordered_map gets empty after inserting an element, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I have an unordered_map object, which I fill somewhere, and when look for what I put, the map is empty.

I have a `ClassA`-object which has a `ClassB` private member. `ClassB` has a private member of `ClassC*` and an `unordered_map<std::string, ClassC*>` private member. It also has public functions `insertClassC(std::string name, ClassC* o)` and `setActiveClassC(std::string name)`. My `main()`-function, has a `ClassC` object, calls `insertClassC()`, and then calls `setActiveClassC()`.

```
int main()
{
    ClassC mainClassC;
    try
    {
        ClassA app;
        app.getClassB().insertClassC("main", &mainClassC);
        app.getClassB().setActiveClassC("main");
    } catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

ClassB ClassA::getClassB()
{
    return classBObject; // private member of ClassA
}

void ClassB::insertClassC(std::string name, ClassC* o)
{
    // classCMap is an unordered_map<std::string, ClassC*>, private member of ClassB
    classCMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, ClassC*> (name, o)); 
}

void ClassB::setActiveClassC(const std::string name)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ClassC*>::const_iterator res = classCMap.find(name);
    if(res == classCMap.end())
    {
        char err [50];
        sprintf(err, "ClassC \"%s\" could not be found", name.c_str());
        throw std::runtime_error(err);
    }
    active = res->second;
}
```

I would expect this program to return `EXIT_SUCCESS`, but it returns `EXIT_FAILURE` and prints to stderr:

```
ClassC "main" could not be found
```

When debugging, I can see that the size of `classCMap` is 1 at the end of the `insertClassC()` call, but it's 0 when I call `setActiveClassC()`.

I suspect my understanding of pointers is wrong (I'm kind of a beginner with c++), so I read stuff about that, but I still don't understand my mistake.

Comment: `app.getClassB()` returns a _copy_ of your private class member. Try changing the signature of `getClassB` to `ClassB& getClassB()` and then it should do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I decided to make my comment an answer:

Your function

```
ClassB ClassA::getClassB()
{
    return classBObject; // private member of ClassA
}
```

has return type `ClassB` which means it *copies* your private member.
But since you want to modify your member, you need to return a reference to your member, i.e. you'd have to write

```
ClassB& ClassA::getClassB()
{
    return classBObject; // private member of ClassA
}
```

Note the ampersand on the return type.